# Типический или типичный. Изменение значения при смене суффикса

Tags: прилагательные, суффиксы

Добрый день. Меня очень давно занимает вопрос о суффиксе -ск- у прилагательных. В текстах, скажем, 19 века чаще встречаются с суфиксом -ск- такие прилагательные, которые сегодня используются с другими суффиксами, но с тем же значением.

типический и типичный

истерический и истеричный

гармонический и гармоничный

Во многих толковых словарях, кстати говоря, в значении одного слова пишут "то же, что и...", а дальше парное ему. Кто-нибудь знает, с чем это связано? Не подскажете, где можно почитать об этом подробнее? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слова «типичный и типический» отличаются суффиксами ИЧН и ИЧЕСК, с которыми и связано различие их значений.

Суффикс ИЧН образует  прилагательные  со значением ХАРАКТЕРНОГО СВОЙСТВА лица или предмета: гармония – гармоничный, тип – типичный. Суффикс ИЧЕСК образует преимущественно относительные прилагательные со значением СВОЙСТВЕННОСТИ ИЛИ СВЯЗАННОСТИ: артист – артистический, тип – типический, причем в качестве мотивирующего слова часто выступают слова из области литературы, искусства или отвлеченные понятия.

Хотя значения суффиксов частично пересекаются и прилагательные образуют синонимичную пару, между ними есть и явное отличие: суффикс ИЧН в большей степени передает ВНУТРЕННИЕ СВОЙСТВА и чаще используется в КАЧЕСТВЕННЫХ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫХ, а суффикс ИЧЕСК  выделяется в  ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНЫХ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫХ. Указанные различия в области применения можно увидеть в толковом словаре.

ТИПИЧНЫЙ,  1.Воплощающий в себе характерные особенности какого-л. типа предметов, лиц, явлений. Типичный южный город.  2. Разг. Ярко выраженный, явный.  Да ведь он типичный карьерист! 3.Часто встречающийся, характерный, обычный, естественный. Типичный случай.
ТИПИЧЕСКИЙ
1. К Тип (5 зн: художественный образ, обобщенные черты.). Типический образ, типические обстоятельства. 2.=Типичный (1, 3 зн.). Типические особенности русской музыки.

Итак, качественное значение, внутренние свойства передает слово «типичный». Слово «типический»  тесно связано с исходным существительным: типические особенности – это особенности данного ТИПА. Это разделение значений, как мне кажется, особенно ясно обозначилось в современном языке и еще не в достаточной мере отражено в словарях. Слово «типичный» явно вытесняет слово «типический», оставляя последнему только  область терминологических значений.

Answer (score 0):

Могу только заметить, что все-таки это не полные синонимы. Например, если "истеричный" говорит больше о черте характера, окраске, то "истирический" - более конкретно о психической болезни.